# how to substring an empty phrase in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a link and I want to substring it into many pieces to get numbers
example:-

```
&OR=-12&MR=24560&MM=20&Mx=110&EOW=1&OW=50&OV=12&CV=-1
```

I want the -12 , 24560 , 20 , ... etc. 
and I did it using this code

```
DECLARE @strprog AS NVARCHAR(MAX)--,@strLM AS NVARCHAR(20),@strLOW AS NVARCHAR(20),@strLOR AS NVARCHAR(20),@strLCR AS NVARCHAR(20),

DECLARE @OR AS SMALLINT, @MR AS SMALLINT, @MM AS SMALLINT, @Mx AS SMALLINT, @EOW AS SMALLINT, @OW AS SMALLINT, @OV AS SMALLINT, @CV AS SMALLINT

SET @strprog='WorkFlow/WFmain.aspx?sservice=WFAppraisalManage&showrep=1&applyRole=0&DisableApproval=1&grbCompQuest=1&EnablecompletionChk=1
&MaxCompletionNo=110&ProficiencyValidation=0&objresulttxt=0

&OR=-12&MR=24560&MM=20&Mx=110&EOW=1&OW=50&OV=12&CV=-1'


SET @OR= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @OR

SET @MR= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @MR

SET @MM= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)-4   )
SELECT  @MM

SET @Mx= SUBSTRING(@strprog, CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)+4 ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @Mx

SET @EOW= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)+5,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)+5 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)+5 ) END -CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)-5 )
SELECT  @EOW

SET @OW= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @OW

SET @OV= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @OV

SET @CV= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @CV
```

The problem is the link could be cut off at any place
example:-

```
&OR=-12&MR=24560&MM=20
```

how can I stop cutting when it reach an end ?
any help ?

Comment: Use split function instead

Answer (score 2):

You can use XML type in MSSQL server to separate the string into lines and get a table with `attribute` and `value` columns. Then you can select any attribute you need from this rowset:

```
DECLARE @strprog AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @strprog='WorkFlow/WFmain.aspx?sservice=WFAppraisalManage&showrep=1&
applyRole=0&DisableApproval=1&grbCompQuest=1&EnablecompletionChk=1
&MaxCompletionNo=110&ProficiencyValidation=0&objresulttxt=0
&OR=-12&MR=24560&MM=20&Mx=110&EOW=1&OW=50&OV=12&CV=-1';

DECLARE @xml as XML;
SET @xml = cast(('<X>'+replace(@strprog,'&' ,'</X><X>')+'</X>') as xml);

WITH T2 as
(
  SELECT N.value('.', 'varchar(1000)') as val FROM @xml.nodes('X') as T(N)
)
SELECT LEFT(val,CHARINDEX('=',val)-1) as attribute,
       SUBSTRING(val,CHARINDEX('=',val)+1,1000) as value
       FROM T2;
```

You get following row set:

```
╔═══════════════════════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║           attribute           ║       value       ║
╠═══════════════════════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║ WorkFlow/WFmain.aspx?sservice ║ WFAppraisalManage ║
║ showrep                       ║ 1                 ║
║ applyRole                     ║ 0                 ║
║ DisableApproval               ║ 1                 ║
║ grbCompQuest                  ║ 1                 ║
║ EnablecompletionChk           ║ 1                 ║
║ MaxCompletionNo               ║ 110               ║
║ ProficiencyValidation         ║ 0                 ║
║ objresulttxt                  ║ 0                 ║
║ OR                            ║ -12               ║
║ MR                            ║ 24560             ║
║ MM                            ║ 20                ║
║ Mx                            ║ 110               ║
║ EOW                           ║ 1                 ║
║ OW                            ║ 50                ║
║ OV                            ║ 12                ║
║ CV                            ║ -1                ║
╚═══════════════════════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

All your substrings are preempted by an equal sign and finished by an ampersand.
Why don't you create a loop to get the string, get value from first equal to the ampersand, drop the part of the string processed from the string and continue doing the same with the rest of the string??

Comment: A loop is a very inefficient way of splitting strings.

Comment: As everything, it depends on what you want to achieve with the loop and the volume of strings that you have to handle...

Comment: Not in this case. Using a loop to split strings is a very poor way to do it. You might not notice the performance on small datasets but there are so many better options than loops. Here are several of them. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Answer (score 0):

You can check the CHARINDEX of each token before setting each variable to see if that token even exists at all in the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @strprog AS NVARCHAR(MAX)--,@strLM AS NVARCHAR(20),@strLOW AS NVARCHAR(20),@strLOR AS NVARCHAR(20),@strLCR AS NVARCHAR(20),

DECLARE @OR AS SMALLINT, @MR AS SMALLINT, @MM AS SMALLINT, @Mx AS SMALLINT, @EOW AS SMALLINT, @OW AS SMALLINT, @OV AS SMALLINT, @CV AS SMALLINT



--SELECT @MR =0, @MM =0, @Mx=0 , @EOW=0, @OW =0, @OV=0


--&OR=-12&MR=24560&MM=20&Mx=110&EOW=1&OW=50&OV=12&CV=-1

SET @strprog='WorkFlow/WFmain.aspx?sservice=WFAppraisalManage&showrep=1&applyRole=0&DisableApproval=1&grbCompQuest=1&EnablecompletionChk=1
&MaxCompletionNo=110&ProficiencyValidation=0&objresulttxt=0

&OR=-12&MR=24560&Mx=110&EOW=1&OW=50&OV=12'

IF CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog) <> 0
SET @OR= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&OR=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @OR

IF CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog) <> 0
SET @MR= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&MR=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @MR

IF CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog) <> 0
SET @MM= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&MM=',@strprog)-4   )
SELECT  @MM

IF CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog) <> 0
SET @Mx= SUBSTRING(@strprog, CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)+4 ,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&Mx=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @Mx

IF CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog) <> 0
SET @EOW= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)+5,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)+5 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)+5 ) END -CHARINDEX('&EOW=',@strprog)-5 )
SELECT  @EOW

IF CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog) <> 0
SET @OW= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&OW=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @OW

IF CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog) <> 0
SET @OV= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&OV=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @OV

IF CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog) <> 0
Set @CV= SUBSTRING(@strprog,CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)+4,CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)+4 ) <=0 THEN LEN(@strprog)+1 ELSE CHARINDEX('&',@strprog,CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)+4 ) END -CHARINDEX('&CV=',@strprog)-4  )
SELECT  @CV
```